# I want to convert the table to pdf using js pdf. But it is not working

Tags: typescript, jspdf

```
  printReceipt(order){ //print receipt pass parameter of client name and its orders
    console.log(order);

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(order.orderClientName, 10, 10); //name of client
    order.orderItem.forEach(a => {
      doc.text(a.productPrice, 10, 10);
      console.log(a.productPrice)
    });
    doc.save(`${order.orderClientName}.pdf`);
  }
```

I am printing multiple times. I have a for each and print the element of array multiple times, but is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working, do you get an error? Can you explain a bit more

Comment: it only prints one item even it is i a loop

Comment: is orderItem an array or a single object? show some structure